# Add content links for Organic Groups

Tags: blocks, organic-groups

I'm using OG and OG Extra to make some kind of community website.. but unfortunately I don't see the group content block even when I added it to a region. .
Please what could be the solution for that and is there any alternative 
Here's images from my configuration:
[image: OG modules installed]
[image: Entity Reference Prepopulate installed]
[image: Eva installed]
[image: The Block is well placed]
[image: But Nothing shown]

Comment: did you clear/flush the cache?

Comment: yes, even manually from the database

Comment: Have you created group content? You should be using a proper view to show it.. Post a screenshot.

Comment: Of course I made a group content. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you also install the [eva](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module, in addition to clearing your caches via admin/config/development/performance.

Also, og_extras only works with og 7.x-2.*.

For the "create content" block, look  for "Node content links" under blocks. You also need to configure the *Organic Group* module to work with the entityreference_prepopulate module, to make it work properly. See [here](https://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups-7x-2x/configuring-content-types-group-%E2%80%9Ccontent-create-links%E2%80%9D) for guidance.